# ElasticSearch 5 - Problems with mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm testing ElasticSearch 5.0 and it seems that I'm missing something obvious here.

In the previous 1.x version, if I wanted to store a document with a field like e-mail, I would just set the field analyzed to "not_analyzed" in the mapping, and then search for the document by email.

Well, I still can't do it in version 5. I set the mapping:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "simple_strings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings_not_analyzed": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
}
```

And I store the document. If I GET index/_search, I get:

```
{
"took": 4,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "common",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": "d5eddb47-ca69-4fdd-838a-9663e8867e0b",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "tenant": "s2auth",
        "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
        "email": "foo@bar.com",
        "password": "foobar",
        "debug": true,
        "id": "d5eddb47-ca69-4fdd-838a-9663e8867e0b"
      }
    }
]
}
}
```

But if I POST this query:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "email": "foo@bar.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get nothing.

I just need to replicate the default mapping behaviour I used in ES 1.x:

```
{
"mappings": {
"_default_": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        { "notanalyzed": {
              "match":              "*", 
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                  "type":        "string",
                  "index":       "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
        }
      ]
   }
}
}
```

Is my mapping definition wrong, my search query wrong or what?

Comment: The name of your mapping type seems to be wrong, instead of `simple_strings`, it should be `user`

Comment: That's correct, but then I'd be setting the mapping for the user type only; I want to set this config as default for any type created.